# Issues animating div with jQuery in IE8

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate, hoverintent

I'm using jQuery to animate 3 sections of a site: http://oceanic.medialounge-dev.co.uk *the ones that say roll over)

They work fine in every browser except in IE8 where they just move around strangely, ironically it works fine in IE7 don't know why, the JS code I'm using is rather simple:

```
jQuery(function($){
        // Global variable so we can check if the rollover box 
        // is at the homepage or inner pages
        var innerBox = ($('.inner-content').length > 0) ? true : false;

        $('.rollover-single').hoverIntent(function(){
            var box    = $(this);

            // Move box up and increase height
            box.animate({
                'margin-top' : (innerBox) ? '-204px' : '-160px',
                'height'     : '260px' 
            });

            // Increase height of hidden content
            box.find('.rollover-content').animate({
                'height' : '204px'
            });

            // Change rollover text
            box.find('.readmore').text('READ MORE');
        }, function(){
            // Same as above but on mouseleave
            var box           = $(this);

            box.animate({
                'margin-top' : '0',
                'height'     : (innerBox) ? '56px' : '100px'
            });

            box.find('.rollover-content').animate({
                'height' : (innerBox) ? '0' : '44px'
            });

            box.find('.readmore').text('ROLL OVER');
        });
    });
```

The `innerBox` variable is just to check if we are on the inner pages since the boxes are smaller there, I'm also using the hoverIntent plugin but back when I used the regular `hover` handle I had the same issues. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!